# How to check if username exists for android studio app

Tags: php, android

I want to check if the username exists in my database. I wrote the following code to check if the username exists but it isn't doing anything. I also don't know how to code in java that's why I put it in my php file. Can someone help me?

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)");

if($username > 0){
    echo "This username is in use.";
}

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

print_r(json_encode($response));
```

Comment: there are some line of code missing. You never set/check `$username`.

Comment: You don't need to check if a username is already present when registering a new user. Simply put a UNIQUE constraint on the username column and catch any errors that MySQL throws at you when you attempt add a new row.

Comment: You have two options: if username is set to be unique you can do an insert if not exists kind of thing (check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql). Or just do a select for that username before and check for rowcount.